# force vagrant VM to prioritize eth1 interface in standard routes

Tags: networking, nat, vagrant

I'm deploying a `vagrant` box (`libvirt`) that needs to serve `podman` containers to the host network.

Somehow the exposed ports of these containers can be accessed from the host network (i.e. on `192.168.1.0/24` but if I configure a NAT/port-forward in the firewall to the `vagrant` VM (`192.168.1.145`) to such ports, it's not accessible from outside, unless I delete the default route on `eth0`.

So, like this I *cannot* access through the port-forward:

```
[root@fedora-rctestenv-vvm ~]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eth1
192.168.121.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

but like this I can:

```
[root@fedora-rctestenv-vvm ~]# eval $(route -n | awk '$0~/[.0]{4}/ && $3~/[.0]{4}/ && $8~/eth0/ { printf "ip route del default via %s dev %s; ",$3,$8 }')
[root@fedora-rctestenv-vvm ~]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eth1
192.168.121.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

Additionally, often the system automatically adds the default route for `eth0` (I don't know which process does this).

So my question: how to specify, preferably directly in the `Vagrantfile` that I **only** want to use the interface/subnet of the host network, and not the VM private network?

Answer (score 1):

Adding this *before* the rest of the provisioning did the trick:

```
     # default router
    config.vm.provision "shell",
        run: "always",
        inline: "route add default gw 192.168.1.1"

    # delete default gw on eth0
    config.vm.provision "shell",
        run: "always",
        inline: "eval $(route -n | awk '$0~/[.0]{4}/ && $3~/[.0]{4}/ && $8~/eth0/ { printf \"ip route del default via %s dev %s; \",$3,$8 }')"
```

A variation of this [is actually mentioned in the docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network), but I failed on my first try some time ago probably because I used the wrong order and put these actions in my `ansible` provisioning script.

Summarising: the above setup probably needs to be done at the beginning of provisioning, and it's no problem to use the `shell` provisioner in combination with the `ansible` provisioner, they're just executed in order of appearance.

Even though the deleted route comes back some time, the new default route with a lower metric remains, which is enough for the needed function:

```
[vagrant@fedora-rctestenv-vvm ~]$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eth1
192.168.121.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

I.e. the "undesired" routes on `eth0` can be ignored as long as the one we need is there and has a lower metric.

It appears it's [not possible to completely get rid of the default NAT network](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/2093), since `vagrant` relies on it too deeply.